# MatLab: Plot cell array with mixed type of data

Tags: matlab, cell, histogram

I have a cell array `C = cell(815,2,14)` with data as in the example below.

The first column represents an observation while the second column represents the number of occurences of this observation. The observation consists of two float values which represent the coordinates inside a 3D bar plot. Both axis of the 3D bar have an interval from [0,1].

I want to create a 3d bar plot using the coordinates of the 1st column and use the number of occurences of the second column as the z-axis.

The plot should look like this: [image]

```
C(:,:,1) = 

'[1 1]'           [511553]
'[0 0]'           [508759]
'[0.85 0.95]'     [  1675]
'[0.7 0.75]'      [   582]
'[0.55 0.75]'     [   359]
....

C(:,:,2) = 

'[1 1]'           [621836]
'[0 0]'           [571582]
'[0.85 0.95]'     [  2134]
'[0.7 0.75]'      [   832]
'[0.55 0.75]'     [   234]
....

.
.
.

....

C(:,:,14) = 

'[1 1]'           [511553]
'[0 0]'           [508759]
'[0.85 0.95]'     [  1675]
'[0.7 0.75]'      [   582]
'[0.55 0.75]'     [   359]
....
```

Comment: The data shouldn't be cell arrays, should they? I think you you have to put the data in a matrix to plot and then modify the labels afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

```
a{1,1} = [5 4 3 2];
a{2,1} = [];
a{3,1} = [5 4 3 2 8];
a{4,1} = [5 3 ];
a{5,1} = [5];
a{6,1} = [3 4 5 6 7 8];
a{7,1} = [5 3 2];

lns = cellfun(@length,a);
mx = max(lns);
mat = NaN;

for ii = 1:numel(a);
    a{ii,1} = [a{ii,1} mat(1,ones(1,mx-lns(ii)))];    
end    

array_vec=cell2mat(a);
```